# How to create specific XML Output

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am using the `XmlWriter` class to create an XML document.

I am able to produce the document as required except for the root element.

I cannot seem to be able to create the the root element with the required attributes which is proving troublesome because of the namespaces and prefixes that are needed.

What I am trying to do is produce output like the following:

```
<prx:rootname xmlns:prx="url1" xmlns:xsi="url2" xsi:schemaLocation="url3">
```

The above is a condensed example of the actual root element needed, the actual URLs are quite verbose for example.

FYI, all other child elements use the same prefix as the root element.

Can I use this class or would I have to use another method to generate the desired XML output?

Comment: You forgot the code...

Comment: And your example output. Personally, I find [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) much easier to use for creating XML.

Comment: I haven't posted any code because the example in my question above is not based-on but is not the actual data. The actual data is financial and I have to be careful what I publish. However, I think I have now figured it out by using the right method overloads for StartElement and SatrtAttribute. I just cannot answer my own question yet (site restriction).